# How to install Nvidia driver on Debian 8 on MSI ge60 gtx960m?

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have installed Debian jessie on my laptop MSI GE60 2QE-893XCN. My Video card is Nvidia GTX960MG.

I have tried following solution. But still don't work.

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90279/en-us

lspci | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

sudo lshw -c display

```
  *-display               
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

And following is the log under `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    14.208] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[    14.208] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    14.208] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    14.208] Current Operating System: Linux debian 4.1.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.1.6-1~bpo8+1 (2015-09-09) x86_64
[    14.208] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.1.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 root=UUID=c35e3d34-72a2-4419-b2cc-2187e0b7198a ro quiet splash nomodeset
[    14.208] Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
[    14.208] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[    14.208] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    14.208]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    14.208] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    14.208] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Oct 11 22:05:41 2015
[    14.223] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    14.223] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    14.271] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    14.271] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    14.271] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    14.284] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    14.285] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    14.285] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    14.285] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    14.285] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    14.327] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    14.327]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    14.349] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    14.349] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    14.349] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    14.349] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    14.349] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    14.362] (II) Loader magic: 0x561fb2b3dd80
[    14.362] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    14.362]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    14.362]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[    14.362]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    14.362]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    14.364] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1462:1107 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    14.364] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:139b:1462:1107 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    14.365] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    14.390] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    15.538] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    15.538]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    15.538]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    15.543] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.65  Tue Dec  2 09:10:06 PST 2014
[    15.549] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    15.549] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    15.549] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    15.549] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    15.549] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    15.549] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    15.571] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    15.615] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.615]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 2.99.917
[    15.615]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.615]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.615] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.615] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    15.638] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.638]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.9.0
[    15.638]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.638]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.638] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    15.638] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    15.638] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.638]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 0.4.4
[    15.638]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.638]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.638] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    15.638] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    15.642] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.642]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.3.3
[    15.642]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    15.642]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.642] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    15.642] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    15.642] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    15.642] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    15.642] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    15.642] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    15.642] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    15.642] (++) using VT number 7

[    15.647] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    15.647] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    15.647] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    15.647] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    15.647] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    15.647] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    15.652] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.652]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    15.652]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.652] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    15.652] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    15.652] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    15.652] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    15.652] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    15.652] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.652]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    15.652]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.652] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    15.652] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    15.652] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    15.652] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    15.652] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    15.652] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    15.652] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    15.652] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    15.652] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    15.658] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.658]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.1.0
[    15.658]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.658] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    15.658] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    15.658] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    15.674] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.674]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    15.674]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    15.674] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    15.675] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    15.675] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    15.675] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    15.675] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 32704 kB
[    15.675] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: Intel(R) HSW Mobile/Desktop Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS
[    15.675] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 0.0
[    15.677] (**) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    15.677] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[    15.677] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    15.677] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    15.677] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    15.677] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    15.678] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    15.699] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[    15.699] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level 2
[    15.699] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 1 sec.
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read successfully
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Manufacturer: LGD  Model: 44f  Serial#: 0
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Year: 2014  Week: 0
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Digital Display Input
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): 6 bits per channel
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 35  vert.: 19
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): redX: 0.625 redY: 0.355   greenX: 0.335 greenY: 0.570
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.050   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): clock: 138.7 MHz   Image Size:  345 x 194 mm
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 1968  h_sync_end 2000 h_blank_end 2080 h_border: 0
[    15.701] (II) VESA(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1083  v_sync_end 1088 v_blanking: 1111 v_border: 0
```

Comment: You may need to use the version maintained in 'Experimental', which is 352.21. The versions in unstable, testing and stable, one of which you already tried, I believe do not support the 900 series Nvidia cards.